# Can't use CreateProcess because of a build error: 'STARTUPINFO': undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, c, winapi, createprocess

I am trying to start the process calc.exe with `CreateProcess(...)`.
When I am building the solution I received the error:
***'STARTUPINFO': undeclared identifier***

[image]

I am not understanding why.
The error is only when building the solution and the variable looks defined.
When pressing **F12** on the variable it appears as:
[image]

Maybe it related to the `#ifdef UNICODE` ?

**Full code:**

```
// CppConsoleApp.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "stdafx.h"

int main()
{
    STARTUPINFO info;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
    ZeroMemory(&info, sizeof(info));
    info.cb = sizeof(info);
    ZeroMemory(&processInfo, sizeof(processInfo));

    LPCWSTR path = L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe";

    if (!CreateProcess(path, NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo))
    {
        printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
    }

    WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: use `/showIncludes` cl option for look, which files actually included. check that file, where `STARTUPINFO` is defined is included. look are this is defined in some `#if` block. check are you go in this block

Comment: Read the MSDN page on _[STARTUPINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331(v=vs.85).aspx)_

Comment: @ryyker - and so what ?

Comment: @RbMm - it describes everything needed to know how to use the STARTUPINFO structure.  Beyond that, you have already provided the hints on #defines.

Comment: @ryyker - and what from this ? but already view that error in `#include "stdafx.h"` **not first** Cheers and hth. - Alf right here. msdn here unrelated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put `#include "stdafx.h"` *first* of all.

Or turn off precompiled headers in the project settings to get standard C++'s preprocessing behavior.

With precompiled headers everything up to the include of the precompiled header, which in your case is `"stdafx.h"`, is ignored.

---

There is a warning about the situation you have, where includes are ignored. If you want to use precompiled headers in general, you should find that warning number and specify that it should be treated as an error.

Comment: Thanks ! So simple and so unclear from the errors. I moved `#include "stdafx.h"` to be the first and now it works.

Comment: Precompiled header files are generated through user-provided header files. As such, the correct syntax is `#include "stdafx.h"`, not `#include <stdafx.h>`.

Comment: @IInspectable: Thanks! Fixed. :)